# Not able to save objects in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am developing one application in grails. I have following kind of mapping. Now I am saving object of ***DemoD*** class but its not saving values neither showing me any error while save. I have printed all created object and all looks fine. but still I am now able to save records.

```
class DemoS {
 String firstName
 String lastName
 Long rollNumber
 String address1
 String address2
 String city
 String state

 static constraints = {
    address2 nullable:true
 }
 static hasMany = [demoAList: DemoA]
}

class DemoD {

 Date date

 static hasMany = [demoAList: DemoA]
 def beforeInsert = {
    date = new Date()
 }
}

class DemoA {

 Long id
 Boolean absent
 Boolean halfday
 String notes
 Date date

 static belongsTo = [demoS:DemoS, demoD:DemoD]
 static constraints = {
    notes nullable: true
 }
}


class UploadDataService {

 def saveUploadedData(def dataList) {
    def i = 0
    DemoD ddObj = new DemoD()

    //Getting this dataList from excel and now creating object for each row.
    dataList?.each{ rowList ->
        if(i != 0){

            def dsObj = DemoS.get(rowList[0]?.longValue())
            DemoA daObj = new DemoA([id:rowList[0]?.longValue(),absent:rowList[1],halfday:rowList[2],notes:rowList[3] ? rowList[3] : ''])

            dsObj.addToDemoAList(daObj)
            daObj.demoS = dsObj
            ddObj.addToDemoAList(daObj)
            daObj.demoD = ddObj
        }
        i++
    }
    ddObj.save(saveOnError: true)
 }
}
```

Comment: Change saveOnError to failOnError

Comment: Thanks @MikeW. Now Its showing me validation related error.